# using gedit 2.30.1 on windows 10 64-bit

Tags: gedit

I also have the windows ubuntu app. My question is, does the windows version of gedit save files with dos or linux line endings? I would like to edit my ubuntu (bash) files in the windows gedit.

Answer (score 1):

#### Does the Windows version of gedit save files with DOS or Linux line endings?

It can do either.

When you save a file, choose the "Line Ending" you require:

[image]